# Workflow Settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

[image]I have set up a workflow for approval of an Item created, how do I create in the same workflow a way of notifying the creator of the item which stage in the workflow it is in?

Comment: Is it the OOTB Approval workflow or did you create your own custom workflow for this?

Comment: It is through the workflow through the sharepoint site

Answer (score 2):

In the workflow you can add `Send Email` activity and use that to send emails during each step.

Also you can log the messages to workflow history list. And the creator can look into that list to find the progress.

Comment: I see the place where it says CC... But, how do I make it apply to a certain person in the Workflow. This name will change reguarly, as there are many different individuals involded in submitting an item in this workflow group. So I guess more specifically, is there an easy way (no coding) to make whatever name is entered in the field, automatically entered to be CCed?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Just click on the button next and use `CurrentItem:FieldName`. Where `FieldName` is the field in current item which contains the user to whom the email should be sent.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. In the CC field I entered CurrentItem:(The Item Name) with spaces, and with no spaces and still it rendered no results.

Comment: Please read the comment.. I asked you to click on the button next to CC

Comment: There is no button next to CC. The only buttons I have are on the right hand side of the field of entry.

Comment: Can you please upload a screen shot? There should be a button for picking the user (address book)

Comment: When you click on the address book icon, what all you can see?

Comment: A select people and groups -- Webpage dialouge

Comment: Ok, in that case you should create an approval workflow using SharePoint Designer and do as I suggested.